# ICS on Desire HD

Tags: custom-roms, htc-desire-hd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I'm planning to wipe my phone and in the process I also decided to try some alternative ROM.

From what I understand MIUI 4 and CyanogenMod 9 should be ICS based, but I can't find these ROMs in a pure form. On XDADevelopers forums, there is gazilion of MIUI and CM ROMS, but all of them seem to have some custom modifications.

I want to go for something reasonably stable right now. So where do I find some ICS ROMs for Desire HD without crazy modifications?

Comment: CM9 doesn't have a stable release yet at all.

Comment: ...and according to [this Meta post](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/782/475), the question is off topic.